# ¿Cuál es el músculo lagarto?

Tags: definiciones, ciencia, vocabulario-médico

Estoy trabajando sobre un diccionario de mapudungun y una de las palabras (challwafün') está definida como:

> El músculo lagarto (del brazo)

¿Alguien sabe cuál es este músculo?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, sólo quería añadir, a modo anecdótico, que el nombre de este músculo en mapudungun está compuesto de **challwa**: pez, pescado y **fün'**: músculo, tendón, nervio. Por lo tanto los mapuche conocen este músculo como "músculo pez".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es el [*bíceps braquial*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BAsculo_b%C3%ADceps_braquial).  Según [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MnrWCnQ):

> 3. m. Músculo grande del brazo, entre el hombro y el codo.

Pero eso no nos dice si es el bíceps o el tríceps.  Otros diccionarios dan más especifidad:

> **Anat.** Bíceps, músculo del brazo, fig. y fam. ([fuente](https://books.google.com/books?id=NCKh_LF4b7gC&pg=PA430) (1999))
>
> La protuberancia que en el brazo señala el músculo bíceps. ([fuente](https://books.google.com/books?id=UHwVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA120) (1911))

Otras fuentes que confirman esto aparecen en Google Books; por ejemplo [este de 1959](https://books.google.com/books?id=2VVZAAAAMAAJ&q=m%C3%BAsculo+brazo+lagarto+b%C3%ADceps&dq=m%C3%BAsculo+brazo+lagarto+b%C3%ADceps&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1upntw5XcAhWHPN8KHfy3DFUQ6AEIWjAG).

Comment: Interesante que lo definen como el músculo grande, ya que ese sería el tríceps que es más grande que el bíceps.

Comment: @guifa - Me imagino que querían decir que es uno de los grandes.